# Facebook Share Titles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey this is probably a stupid question. Our organization is currently working on a replatform and we are almost done! At this point we're just fixing tiny bugs, like this one.

If I were to copy/paste this URL into Facebook, it would supply the correct title/description for the article automatically: http://prod-www.startribune.com/isle-royale-wolf-population-plummets-to-three/300340911/

However if I were to copy/paste THIS url into facebook, it would choose the first text it encounters after the start of the section of the page it scrolls to. http://prod-www.startribune.com/isle-royale-wolf-population-plummets-to-three/300340911/#comments

The only difference in the URL's is the addition of #comments to the end.

What I'm wondering, how would I have the #comments URL provide the same title/description that is pulled into facebook that the page does when you go to it sans #comments fragment?

Do I just need to redeclare the meta tags in that part of the page?

Comment: If you use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ it will tell you what it sees and what it uses

Comment: Facebook also suggests you use proper Open Graph tags. They have a section in their docs called "Sharing best Practices for Websites". See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Comment: I have open graph tags on the page, which is why it's so weird that going to the comments part of the page produces different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that there really isn't an issue. All of the URLs generated for canonical and og:url are pointing to what, ultimately, will be the home for the articles, but currently those URLs don't exist yet. I have a feeling this will be a non-issue once the replatform code goes live.